# How to render a web page in a portlet view?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, jsrender, jsr286

Can any one please guide me that how can we render the custom web page view in the portlet?

For example, I have a input text box in my where user can enter the target URL and on click of the submit button the portlet content should display the target URL page.

I don't want to use the existing core portlet (IFrame). I need to design my own with some business logic.

Any guidelines or suggestions on how to render a webpage in the portlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a question on how to build a basic portlet. Please check [a tutorial](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths/-/knowledge_base/6-2/beginning-liferay-development) (step-by-step).

If this is not your question, please specify further - your question is way too broad to assume that you have a specific (other) problem.

Comment: I have created my portlet and deployed it. Now the issue is I need to load my portlet content with external web page like (http://localhost:8080/MyPrj/MyPage). My liferay is running on port 9090 but I need to load a page which is running on port 8080. What logic do I need to implement in view,jsp to render the external webpage

Comment: ?? If you want to render that content in an iframe, render an iframe. If you want to redirect there, do so (this you'll most likely need to do through JS and it's considered bad practice in the portal world - imagine two different portlets on the page redirecting to two different locations. One will win). If you want to just render the content from your 8080 server, use a HttpClient to request it and pipe the output to the portlet.

Comment: Yes, I want to render the content from 8080 server. How can I use HttpClient request and pipe the output to my portlet.

Comment: I'm really new to this portlet and liferay world. I don't know it may be simple but I'm spending couple of days to achive it, still no use. Can you please suggest some guidelines or any documentation for how to use HttpClient request and pipe the output to my portlet.

Comment: Hi . Vinod were you able to find a solution? I'm working on a similar requirement to stream a website using portlet, would like to know how you got it working.